# Notice: Undefined index: steamid in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 468

Tags: php

So when I am not logged in to my site via steam it shows this error (
Notice: Undefined index: steamid in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 468) but when I log in via steam it is gone.

CODE:

```
  <?php if(isadmin($_SESSION['steamid'])){
  echo'Admin tools: [<a href="chatadm.php?do=clear" onclick="return popitup(\'chatadm.php?do=clear\');">clear chat</a>], [<a href="chatadm.php?do=toggle" onclick="return popitup(\'chatadm.php?do=toggle\');">turn '.(chaton() ? 'off' : 'on').'</a>]';
} ?>
```

Line 468 is this line:

```
<?php if(isadmin($_SESSION['steamid'])){
```

Hope someone can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if array index is set like below

```
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['steamid']) && isadmin($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because 'steamid' is not set to the session array.

You need to check also if it is set.

try something like:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']) && isadmin($_SESSION['steamid'])){
```

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php